# Getting Converting Value Error While Sending Data With Python Requests Module

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Hello I'm trying to send a data with python requests module. I'm getting that "Converting Value Error" when I execute it. I don't know what is this error means. Thanks for any help.

Here is my error:

```
{'statusCode': 200, 'statusMessage': 'OK', 'result': None, 'errors': [{'field': '', 'message': 'Error converting value "{"price": 64, "stock": 11, "expiration": "2021-08-18 17:41:50.956382+00:00", "product": {"name": "Cerave Hydrating Cleanser Nemlendircili Temizleyici 236 ml", "barcode": "3337875597180"}}" to type \'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DataTransferObjects.Listings.CreateOutSourcedListingModel]\'. Path \'\', line 1, position 207.'}]}
```

My code is here:

```
  token = self.get_token()
  create_listing_path = "api/v1/listings/createlistings"
  create_listing_url = "https://staging.lab.xxx.com/" + create_listing_path
  bearer = "Bearer "+str(token)
  headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': bearer}
  fiyat = kart.urun.satis_fiyat
  stok = kart.stok
  son_kullanma = kart.expiration
  barkod = kart.urun.barkod
  urun_adi = kart.urun.urun_adi
  data = {'price':int(fiyat),'stock':int(stok), 'expiration':str(son_kullanma), 'product':{'name':urun_adi,'barcode':barkod}}
  data_json = json.dumps(data)
  r = requests.request("POST", str(create_listing_url), json=data_json, headers=headers)
```

And here is the information from the documentation at server side:

```
Request Format:
Url: https://staging.lab.xxx.com/api/v1/listings/createlistings
HTTP METHOD: POST

Request Headers:
Content-Type: application/json

Parameters:
[
  {
    "price": 0, (Required)
    "stock": 0, (Required)
    "expiration": "2019-06-21T13:37:40.291Z",
    "maxCount": 0,
    "description": "string",
    "isFeatured": true,
    "product": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string", (Required)
      "barcode": "string", (Required)
      "psf": 0,
      "vat": 0,
      "image": "string"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This is a server-side error. You need to check what content the API is expecting.

Comment: I've added that information

Comment: Looks like it is expecting a list. Did you try `data = [{ .... }]`?

Comment: Yes. When I tried that I got this error: "ValueError('too many values to unpack (expected 2)'),". I think it is expecting json data because of headers but I'm not expert :)

Comment: But when I try with " data={'price': int(fiyat),'stock':int(stok), 'expiration':str(son_kullanma), 'product':{'name':urun_adi,'barcode':barkod} }" I got a new error: "{'statusCode': 200, 'statusMessage': 'OK', 'result': None, 'errors': [{'field': '', 'message': "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: p. Path '', line 0, position 0."}]}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That solved my problem:

```
data = [{'price':int(fiyat),'stock':int(stok),'expiration':str(son_kullanma),'product':{'name':urun_adi,'barcode':barkod}}]
r = requests.request("POST", str(create_listing_url), data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

data=data wasn't worked for me. Than I followed that answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34051771/11027652