# Understanding the difference between these two python requests POST calls (data vs. json args)

Tags: python, api, python-requests

This is a toy, non-reproducible example as I can't share the original. I think it's answerable, and might help others. From other SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685248/difference-between-data-and-json-parameters-in-python-requests-package) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051500/python-requests-getting-back-unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-va), my understanding is that given some dictionary `d` of params, these are equivalent:

```
requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(d))
requests.post(url, json=d)
```

The parameters for a token endpoint were defined in documentation like so:

- url: {{base_url}}/token
- parameters

  - grant_type={{password}}
  - username={{username}}
  - password={{password}}
  - scope={"account":"{{account}}", "tenant":"{{tenant}}"}

I started with this, with variables loaded from a .env file:

```
resp = requests.post(f'{base_url}/token',
                     json={'grant_type': 'password', 'username': uname, 'password': pwd,
                           'scope': {'account': account, 'tenant': tenant}})
resp.text
# '{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}'
```

I tried changing to the data argument, and got a more sane error:

```
resp = requests.post(f'{base_url}/token',
                     data={'grant_type': 'password', 'username': uname, 'password': pwd,
                           'scope': {'account': account, 'tenant': tenant}})
resp.text
# '{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"{\\"ErrorMessage\\":\\"Error trying to Login  - User [username] Account [] Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: a.
```

I tried a few other things like forcing quotes around args (e.g. `{'account': f"{account}"}`) without success, and ultimately succeeded with this "hybrid" method:

```
resp = requests.post(f'{base_url}/token',
                 data={'grant_type': 'password', 'username': uname, 'password': pwd,
                       'scope': json.dumps({'account': account, 'tenant': tenant})})
```

My questions:

- is this nuance "real" vs. the straightforward reading of the linked questions? Namely, it seemed like one *either* uses `data=json.dumps(d)` or `json=d`, but I have not found an answer mixing the two (and wrapping the entire `data` arg in `json.dumps()` breaks my working final version)
- as a relative noob in APIs/network things, would this be discernible to me from the documentation arguments listed above, or was trial and error the only way to discover this?
- given my final solution was there a better/more correct way to pass these params?

Comment: It appears to me that the documentation is incorrect.  Having a json string as the value of a field within a dictionary is not uncommon.  Badly written documentation is also not uncommon.  But anytime you have a dictionary within another dictionary, you should expect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big difference in providing `json=` or `data=` argument.

Providing `json=` will send `Content-Type: application/json` and will format the data you sent as json-string. E.g. the following request:

```
resp = requests.post(url, json={"a": 42, "b": 55})
```

Will result in the server receiving this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:12001
User-Agent: python-requests/2.28.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/json


{"a": 42, "b": 55}
```

whereas sending the same as data will send it as form data with content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
resp = requests.post(url, data={"a": 42, "b": 55})
```

Will result in the server receiving this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:12001
User-Agent: python-requests/2.28.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 9
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded


a=42&b=55
```

If you are using the `data=json.dumps(...)` variant, you essentially pass a single string as data. The string is json-format but requests does not know this (it could be anything). In this case, it seems, requests does not send any `Content-Type`, you would have to explicitly set it in the code.

Now, which variant is correct, depends on the API you are using, but as the data seems to be structured, it cannot be encoded well into form-data, so probably json is what you want to send.

With respect to the mixed solution, I would argue that it shows that the API is very ill-designed, but here is what the server receives:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:12001
User-Agent: python-requests/2.28.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 145
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded


grant_type=password&username=treuss&password=s3cret&scope=%7B%22account%22%3A+%22treuss%40stackoverflow.com%22%2C+%22tenant%22%3A+%22tenant%22%7D
```

Everything after `scope=` is the encoded json-string generated from the `json.dump` in your example, i.e. an url-encoded version of the string `{"account": "treuss@stackoverflow.com", "tenant": "tenant"}`

Comment: This was very helpful on background/general details. Could you expand your conclusion to specifically cover when/why one would need `data={'a': 42, 'b': json.dumps(...)})`, which is the eventual solution I found. I didn't see your answer covering what I felt was a sort of "mixed" case, and that's why I felt my question was novel vs. other SO questions advising either/or.

Comment: The answer to "when/why one would need" is imho "if someone has to use a really badly designed API". See the edit about what it sends.